# Cluster_size function is not available

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, clustering, size

I'm using the version 3.28.2.
I combined the points in a cluster, and now I'd like to define the size of the cluster depending on the number of the points in cluster. However, the function cluster_size is not available in the list of the functions.
[image]

Comment: The variable @cluster_size is context-dependent. So it depends where you access the expression string builder if it is available or not.

Answer (score 3):

The `cluster_size` function should be located under `Variables` as shown below:

[image]

I am using `QGIS 3.28.2` in Windows, but I am not sure about other operating systems. If you still cannot find it, try to reinstall QGIS again. Sometimes, reinstallation solves some problems like the one you have.